# check if excel instance already exist Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how can i check if an instance of a workbook already exist? During my programm i would be able to close excel without the application crash...
When i'm using the instance in the programm i want to check if the instance exist when not, i open it again...
thanks

```
Dim neue_excelinstanz As excelapp.Application

Dim neue_workbook As excelapp.Workbook

Dim neue_worksheet As excelapp.Worksheet


    neue_excelinstanz = CType(CreateObject("Excel.Application"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)

    neue_workbook = CType(neue_excelinstanz.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\global.xlsx"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)


    neue_worksheet2 = CType(neue_workbook.Worksheets(2), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it maybe just be an If block? Im not sure how to code in German, but:

```
If neue_workbook Is Nothing Then
    neue_workbook = CType(neue_excelinstanz.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Nicolas Grichting\Desktop\Vmc_vapeur\global.xlsx"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook)
End If
```

I would maybe also use threading.sleep to give it time to load before having the program try it again. But this depends on how youre using this.